# ReleaseHttpClientBase Socket Exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, fiddler, socketexception

I am working with the ReleaseHttpClientBase in the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Release package, and I am getting some strange behaviour. So I am calling the GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync on each of my TFS projects, but I get a socket exception from TFS. The weird part is if I am running Fiddler it works every time. I cannot figure this out.

```
public IEnumerable<ReleaseDefinition> GetReleaseDefinitions()
    {
        IEnumerable<CatalogNode> collectionNodes = GetCollectionNodes();
        IEnumerable<ReleaseDefinition> releaseDefinitions = new List<ReleaseDefinition>();
        //collectionNodes = collectionNodes.Skip(4);
        foreach(var collectionNode in collectionNodes)
        {
            var uri = new Uri(TfsUri,collectionNode.Resource.DisplayName);
            var releaseClient = GetHttpClient(uri);
            IEnumerable<string> projectNames = GetListOfProjectNames(collectionNode);
            foreach(string projectName in projectNames)
            {
                releaseDefinitions = releaseDefinitions.Concat(releaseClient.GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync(project: projectName).Result);
            }
            releaseClient.Dispose();
        }
        return releaseDefinitions;
    }
```

Comment: Fiddler is creating a cookie which is allowing the connection to work.  The cookies is getting expired and doesn't work when Fiddler is not working.

Comment: Is there a way to set the cookie in my app?

Comment: I usually capture the fiddler results and then add missing header to my application that I find in the fiddler results.